# I cannot delete the file in my app

Tags: java, android

I programmed a simple notes app, so there are three activities, one (MainActivity) is for the text field with a button to save the content in the textfield as .txt, another activity (Notizen_Ansehen) is for the list, what shows all .txt files saved. The third activity (Edit_Notes) is for editing the content of the .txt and saving it by leaving the activity, also there is a button in this activity to delete this file, when I click on the button to delete, but this file isn't deleted and still exists, this is the problem, it should be deleted. Since weeks now I try to find the mistake by google and research, still I don't get on the mistake so I decided to ask you, here's my code:

Edit_Notes_Activity.java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if(!(isDeleted)) {
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(notefile);
                outputStream.write(editText2.getText().toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        super.onPause();
        this.recreate();
    }

  ---->      private void deleteNote() {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Edit_Notes_Activity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Notiz löschen?");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Löschen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    notefile.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notiz wurde gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isDeleted = true;
                    finish();                     <----


            }
        });
```

I don't know if you need also the .xml datas to find the mistake, but I'd be very glad if you could help me to find the problem. If you need more than the activities, just write it, I'll send them.
I shortened the code now, the problem is I dont know what is important and where the mistake could be so I let a bit of every activity.
Thanks for your help!

Declaring notefile:

```
String notetext;
File notefile;

    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT") && getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE")){

        notetext = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT");
        notefile = (File) getIntent().getExtras().get("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE");

        editText2.setText(notetext);

    }
```

Back to list after editing:

```
protected void onPause() {

    if(!(isDeleted)) {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(notefile);
            outputStream.write(editText2.getText().toString().getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
    }
    super.onPause();
    this.recreate();
}
```

Every code with notefile:

Edit Notes Activity:

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT") && getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE")){

            notetext = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT");
            notefile = (File) getIntent().getExtras().get("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE");

            editText2.setText(notetext);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if(!(isDeleted)) {
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(notefile);
                outputStream.write(editText2.getText().toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        super.onPause();
        this.recreate();
    }

    private void deleteNote() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Edit_Notes_Activity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Notiz löschen?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Löschen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                notefile.delete();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notiz wurde gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isDeleted = true;
                notefile.delete();
                finish();
                notefile.delete();


            }
        });
```

Notizen Ansehen Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notizen_ansehen_);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayListSetup();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Notizen_ansehen_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, texteliste);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent editIntent = new Intent(Notizen_ansehen_Activity.this, Edit_Notes_Activity.class);
                editIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT", texteliste.get(position));
                editIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE", dateinliste.get(position));
                startActivity(editIntent);


            }

        });

   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notizen_ansehen_);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayListSetup();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Notizen_ansehen_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, texteliste);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent editIntent = new Intent(Notizen_ansehen_Activity.this, Edit_Notes_Activity.class);
                editIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT", texteliste.get(position));
                editIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE", dateinliste.get(position));
                startActivity(editIntent);


            }

        });

    }
```

EXTRA_NOTE_FILE and EXTRA_NOTE_TEXT are for getting the value of the data and the content I guess, actually it's been a while since I wrote the code and do not remember everything, but I guess you can figure that out easily in the code.
It's important for edit them, so if you click on the item in the list the code knows where this item was, which file it is and what content this item in the list has.

Comment: Still very unclear. So you have a list and write the items of that list to file. Then you delete te file and the list still contains the same items? Looks normal to me.

Comment: Sorry my first question I dont know what you need to hear :D

Comment: Yes, I save these "items" as .txt, what get listed in another activity. Now I have the option to delete a .txt but when I try to delete them they still exist, I dont find the problem

Comment: Well it can be your first question but i do not understand a word of your problem. So try to describe it better. Indeed i will not look at your code before you have told what your code should do and what it does not.

Comment: `Now I have the option to delete a .txt but when I try to delete them they still exist,`. So you try to delete a .txt file? And you cannot delete that file? One? Then why do you speak of them? As them is more files.

Comment: Humm.. so there are three activities, one (MainActivity) is for the text field with a button to save the content in the textfield as .txt, another activity (Notizen_Ansehen) is for the list, what shows all .txt files saved. The third activity (Edit_Notes) is for editing the content of the .txt and saving it by leaving the activity, also there is a button in this activity to delete this file, when I click on the button to delete, but this file isnt deleted and still exists, this is the problem, it should be deleted.

Comment: Well yeah sorry I mean exactly this one file I just edit.

Comment: Well then remove all code. Just post code to delete a file. Do not explain your problem in comments but in your post.

Comment: I shortened the code now, the code for delete is signed with --> <-- but I guess the problem isn't there, I guess the problem is in the list-activity.

Comment: You still have much to much code. So `notefile.delete();` does not work? Then show how you instantiate `notefile`. Nobody is interested in activities or alert builders or clicking menu items. Show only the code to delete a file. Ten lines will do i think. Remove the rest.

Comment: so, I hope it's short enough now :D

Comment: Show how you declare and instantiate `notefile` as nobody sees what it is.

Comment: `notefile.delete();` Check the return value. Do not just toast that the file was deleted.  Do not set isDeleted to true before you checked the return value.

Comment: I am pretty nooby in programming, how do I check the return "value" and what is this value?
What do you mean with instantiate?

Comment: If (notefile.delete()) { toast file deleted} else { toast sorry could not delete file }

Comment: Just show all concerning notefile.

Comment: `File notefile;`. So notefile is a File instance. But it is not really instantiated. Mostly you will connect it with a file path. You did not show that. Show all concerning notefile.

Comment: `notefile = (File) getIntent().getExtras().get("EXTRA_NOTE_FILE");`.  ??? Does that compile? What is the value of notefile.getAbsolutePath() after that statement?

Comment: So, I posted every code with notefile or NOTE_FILE, I explained what I think this EXTRA_NOTE_FILE is.

Comment: Sorry but that is much to much code. I will not figure it out. What should we do with edit texts an on pauzes? `What is the value of notefile.getAbsolutePath()`. You did not even take the effort to answer my question.

Comment: Can you tell me please how I can figure out the value?